# Ambari + HDP licensing

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I'm experiencing a deployment and management of a Hadoop cluster and I found out that, for the purpose, Ambari is a very useful and convenient tool.
Now I'm trying to figure out if all the licenses of the HDP stack allow to deploy a Hadoop installation also in a production environment.
Does anyone have experience in the use of Ambari in production? Is it completely free to use also for production environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an employee of Hortonworks myself, I can assure you that there is no licensing that you have to comply with to deploy Ambari, including Ambari as bundled into HDP; http://hortonworks.com/hdp/.  Now... we would LOVE for you to buy a support contract!  ;-)